# break statement for foreach loop not working as planned using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, foreach, break

I've been wanting to know how to break a foreach loop where i can get the output without going through the whole element stored in it. My problem is, whenever i use the break statement to stop get the 2nd element, the first element is also showing up. Like when you want to only get the 2nd element, in return it will display the 1st element and the 2nd element. I only want the 2nd element to appear.

To better explain this, here is my code:

```
 public partial class Pages_GuitarItemsIbanezDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private string guitarBrandType = "Ibanez";
   private int x = 0;
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    FillPage();
   }

   public void FillPage()
   {
    ArrayList itemDetails = new ArrayList();


    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        itemDetails = ConnectionClass.GetItems("%");
    }
    else
    {
        itemDetails = ConnectionClass.GetItems(guitarBrandType);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();




        foreach (GuitarItems gList in itemDetails)
        {

            sb.Append(
                string.Format(
                    @"<div class='guitarItemsDetailsWrapper'>
                        <div class='guitarItemsDetailsImage'>
                            <img runat='server' src='{3}' />
                        </div>

                        <div class='guitarItemsDetailsStyle'>
                            <h2>Name: </h2><p>{0} {1}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Price: </h2><p>${2}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Description: </h2><p>{4}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Neck Type: </h2><p>{5}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Body: </h2><p>{6}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Fretboard: </h2><p>{7}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Bridge: </h2><p>{8}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Neck Pickup: </h2><p>{9}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Bridge Pickup: </h2><p>{10}</p>
                            <br/>
                            <h2>Hardware Color: </h2><p>{11}</p>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>", gList.Type, gList.Model, gList.Price, gList.Image2, gList.Description, gList.NeckType,
                    gList.Body, gList.Fretboard, gList.Bridge, gList.NeckPickup, gList.BridgePickup, gList.HardwareColor));

        if (++x == 2)
        {
            break;
        }

       }




    lblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();



}
}
```

As you can see here in my foreach loop section. I've tried breaking it from the 3rd loop using if statement so it can display the 2nd element but instead, it will the display the 1st element and the 2nd element. Hope you guys can help me out on displaying only the 2nd element. Feel free to edit and suggest better code techniques.

Comment: If you only want the second element -- then why loop at all?

Comment: A loop is basically do something for everything. A break stops the loop but everything the loop has done is done. Access the list using an indexer eg something like `itemDetails[1]`.

Comment: You've picked quite possibly the most difficult (and difficult to maintain) way ever to do this.

Comment: If your only problem is the `break` statement, I would start by separating the conditional statement from the increment, as in `x++; if (x == 2)` Combining them is just a bit too clever.

Comment: could you just use `var secondItem = itemDetails[1];` then use `secondItem` as needed

Comment: Secondly, if the point of this is to loop through the first two (or three) items, then just use a `for` loop with an index.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this(although not a proper way). Just continue loop if not 2(before your append). Please review this one

```
foreach (GuitarItems gList in itemDetails)
        {
        if (x != 2)
        {
            x++;
            continue;
        }
            sb.Append(
                string.Format(
                    @"<div class='guitarItemsDetailsWrapper'>
                        ....
                    </div>", gList.Type, gList.Model, gList.Price, gList.Image2, gList.Description, gList.NeckType,
                    gList.Body, gList.Fretboard, gList.Bridge, gList.NeckPickup, gList.BridgePickup, gList.HardwareColor));

        if (x == 2)
        {
            break;
        }
        x++;
       }
```

Yes, above was terrible solution to use `foreach` loop just to get specific item by index. It was to pointed out that the problem was, your `sb.Append` is triggered for each loop (before you break it). To solve that we can use `continue` before your `sb.Append` code to skip current iteration (It is useful but not in this scenario).
At last, to get specific item based on index please follow advice from commenters above. Such as to use

```
var secondItem = itemDetails[1]
```

or another query like

```
using System.Linq;
var queryItem = itemDetails.Where(i=>i.Type.Contains("something")).FirstOrDefault();
```

so in your case try something like this one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var itemDetails = new List<Guitar>(){
                new Guitar("Electric", "KA123"),
                new Guitar("Manual", "model2"),
                new Guitar("Get this one", "main model")
            };

            // only this one line code needed to get specific item by index
            var gList = itemDetails[2];                

            Console.WriteLine("Type:{0}, Model:{1}", gList.Type, gList.Model);
        }

        public class Guitar 
        {
            public Guitar(string type, string model) {
                Type = type;
                Model = model;
            }
            public string Type {get;set;}
            public string Model {get;set;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it does not display anything at all.

Comment: okay finally it worked. Would you mind also making an example for the proper way of doing it?

Comment: I added example above, please review it